# Prove that if $x $ is transcendental over $F $ then $t^2-x \in F (x)[t] $ is irreducible

Tags: field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

> Prove that if $x $ is transcendental over $F $ then $t^2-x \in F (x)[t] $ is irreducible

My approach: suppose there is $b $ a square root of $x $. Writing $b=f (x)/g (x) $, $f, g $ relatively prime has that, eventually, $h(t) := [f(t)]^2-[g(t)]^2t $ has $x $ as a root. If $h $ is identically zero then we get that $f (0) = 0$ and since $f,g $ are prime to each other we get that $g (0) \neq 0$, i.e. the coefficient of $t $ in $h $ is nonzerox i.e. $h $ is not identically zero, contradicting our assumptioj that $h =0$. Hence it must he that $h $ is a nonzero polynomial with $x $ as a root, contradicting that $x $ is transcendental.

Comment: It's just the observation that $x$ has no square root in $F(x)$.

Comment: If it were reducible over $F(x)$ it'd have a root, in other words an element of $F(x)$ that squares to $x$, but no element of $F(x)$ squares to $x$. Can you prove this? (Also, the quotient $F(x)/(x)$ doesn't make sense to write here - it's the trivial ring since $(x)$ is all of $F(x)$.)

Comment: I am currently doing the same question and also thought of doing this problem using contradiction. However, I am stuck at trying to prove that given $y^2=x$, that $y \not\in F(x)$. Any hints would be welcome.

Comment: I find the edit a bit strange. You want $b=f(x)/g(x)$. Here $x$ is an element of the base field $F(x)$ and $t$ is the indeterminate in the polynomial $t$. After all, you do ask for irreducibilty in $F(x)[t]$. Irreducibility in $F(t)[x]$ is trivial because the polynomial is then linear.

Comment: Anyway, you can follow the hint in Lord Shark's comment. One way of doing that is to use unique factorization in $F[x]$ and proceed exactly the way of the standard proof of irrationality of $\sqrt2$. Another approach would be to apply Eisenstein's criterion with the prime (=irreducible) $x$. Of course, you then first need to justify the use of Eisenstein's criterion, but the proof is analogous to the integer/rational case.